# kafka connect consumer group members with no assigments available

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka connect task which fetches data from a topic with 3 partitions and send the data to a cassandra sink, so I have kconnect in distributed mode with max task up to 3. This is fine, it works really great. But last week I saw more members in the consumer group than the max tasks. It doesn't look an error because I see 3 assigned and the rest are shown as "No assignments available". So it seems like old used clients.

**Why does this happens?**

**How can I self-purge these old members?**

**Can I delete these, not anymore, used members?**

Here you can see a screenshot of the members of the topic, the dark blue ones in the column assignments are the "good" working ones, three and reading from different partitions 0,1,2.

The rest are the "unused" with no assignments available.

[image: consumer groups with no assignments available]

Comment: If the host and id is unique it's a different row since the workers don't dedupe on name alone

Comment: @OneCricketeer could it be is because we are using kubernetes and those ids are coming from old pods?

Comment: You could use StatefulSets to keep the id the same.

Comment: @GonnenDaube kakfka connect has no state ,  Everything is stored at kafka , even configs. How can i do what you suggest?

Comment: I don't really have experience using Kafka connect, but in kubernetes you can simply use StatefulSet instead of Deployments to achieve consistent pod ips. Simply swap your current Deployment with StatefulSet type. https://medium.com/stakater/k8s-deployments-vs-statefulsets-vs-daemonsets-60582f0c62d4